# How can I know which cluster of self-organizing map (SOM) an element belongs to in python?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, som, self-organizing-maps

I am new with clustering and neural nets, and I have just started using Self-Organizing Maps (SOM) to perform some clustering. I have a 15 dimensional dataset and I created a som with the next code:

```
size = 20
from minisom import MiniSom    
som = MiniSom(size, size, 15, sigma=0.3, learning_rate=0.9, random_seed=149)
som.train_random(data, 650000, verbose=True)
```

And I plotted the som the next way:

```
plt.figure()
plt.pcolor(som.distance_map().T, cmap='Blues')
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

My question is: if I have a new 15 dimensional element, how can I know which cluster of the som belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

Best Matching Unit (BMU)

```
for t in itertools.count():
        i =  np.random.choice(range(len(data)))
        bmu = self.find_bmu(data[i])
```

[Finding the Best Matching Unit](https://tcosmo.github.io/2017/07/27/fun-with-som.html)

> create n x n map with random node vector values
>
> loop while s < StepsMax times
>
> compute what a "close" node means, based on s
>
> compute a learn rate, based on s
>
> pick a random data item
>
> determine the map node closest to data item (BMU)
>
> for-each node close to the BMU
>
> adjust node vector values towards data item
>
> end-loop

[SOM - BMU](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/01/01/self-organizing-maps-python.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that MiniSom has a function implemented for this:

```
som.winner(*input_data*)
```

which returns the node that it is closest to.